# Java 8 - packaging whole app and dependencies using MVN in one big jar (2018)

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies, packaging

What is the 2018 best practice for packaging whole app and all java dependencies into 1 big jar using MVN so that can be executed on any machine (with JRE)?

I've seen this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>de.ntcomputer</groupId>
    <artifactId>executable-packer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.example.MyMainClass</mainClass>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>pack-executable-jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I've also seen something like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.ntcomputer</groupId>
    <artifactId>executable-packer-maven-plugin-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>de.ntcomputer</groupId>
                <artifactId>executable-packer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>de.ntcomputer.executablepacker.test.Test</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>pack-executable-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.examlpe</groupId>
            <artifactId>example-dependency</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Or via Shade plugin:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>com.group.id.Launcher1</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

There might be other approaches as well..

**Some of these are old (e.g. recommended 5y ago) and not sure if they are still valid/maintained/recommended.**

Out of all these choices (or others not noted here) - what is recommended and best practice for packaging everything in 1 jar for Java 8 in 2018?

**Bonus points if someone can give example with 'HelloWorld' java file, corresponding POM file and MVN command to run/create jar with dependencies and then command to execute a made jar.**

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest using the [Spring Boot Maven plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html) - it does exactly what you ask, and doesn't require you use Spring. It does a nicer job than whacking the whole lot together into one giant jar. It also has the advantage, if you are on UNIX, of making the result [executable and a daemon](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html).

Comment: First which one of them are old? maven-shade-plugin in this version 1.6 is old yes but you should use a more recent version of it See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/ (3.1.0) or maybe you can use maven-assembly-plugin (simple variant). Furthermore if you use spring boot maven plugin it will package several deps in your resulting jar you don't like to have except if you are working with spring boot....BTW: Yes Maven and also all the plugins (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/) are still maintained.

Comment: I should be more clear - when I said 'old' - I ment - saw it in 'old posts / old tutorials' and not sure if they are still valid..